# Profile navigation appearing on two lines

Tags: bug, feature-request

Today I was looking for "Votes" in my user profile and didn't see it at first since it's been bumped to appear by itself on a second line.

[image]

There seems to be more than enough room to fit everything on one line with only some very minor layout adjustment.  For example:

```
.s-navigation {
    flex-wrap: initial;
}
```

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature request but it would be nice if we could clean up this detail.